# Using enumerations

Tags: c++, class, enums

I can't understand one problem:

**Types.hpp**:

```
enum SomeEnum { one, two, three };
```

**First.hpp**:

```
#include "Types.hpp"
class First
{
   public: void someFunc(SomeEnum type) { /* ... */ }
};
```

**Second.hpp**:

```
#include "Types.hpp"
#include "First.hpp"
class Second
{
   public: void Foo()
   {
      First obj;
      obj.someFunc(two); // two is from SomeEnum
   }
};
```

Thee error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘First::someFunc(SomeEnum)’
note: candidate is: void First::someFunc(First::SomeEnum)
```

Comment: Are you missing .cpp files?  From your list I don't see the actual implementation of the `First::someFunc` call.

Comment: Not reproducible. What is `EnvironTypes`?

Comment: You don't appear to be showing us all the code...

Comment: This is not the full code. The compiler somewhere has seen EnvironTypes. Do you have an idea where?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace real code to the sample.

Comment: @Ockonal: Please show how do you compile the file.

Comment: @Ockonal: That code seems correct and should compile. Try to boil down your real code to something like this example code by commenting out more and more stuff. Very likely you'll find the problem this way. If not, you have a real repro case to come back here with.

Comment: @KennyTM @sbi unfortunatelly, the code of First class is from another lib and developers said to you it as I described in post.

Comment: Okay, I connected with developers. There was an error in code. They have declared `SomeEnum` again in the class. Thanks all.

Comment: Everything else aside, this code **needs include guards**. It’s pure luck that it works at all.

Comment: @konrad-rudolph there are include guards. I don't think that they should be presented in the sample code.

Comment: btw, your enum `one`, `two`, `three` will have values `0`, `1`, `2` respectively... ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just changed that:

```
no matching function for call to ‘First::someFunc(SomeEnum)’
note: candidate is: void First::someFunc(First::SomeEnum)
```

wasn't this:

```
no matching function for call to ‘First::someFunc(SomeEnum)’
note: candidate is: bool First::someFunc(First::SomeEnum)
```

Anyway, this changes the things. Is the enum declared inside `class First` ? If so, or if you don't know, just try to call the function, puttung `First::` in front of the enum:

```
obj.someFunc( First::two ); // two is from SomeEnum
              ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I might bt totally wrong in interpreting the complier error but

```
note: candidate is: void First::someFunc(First::SomeEnum)
```

Leads me to believe that you declared SomeEnum inside First's definition

```
class First
{
    SomeEnum {one, two, three};
}
```